# Sequence of coprime numbers

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

Fix a prime $p$ and positive integers $r,a,x,y$ such that $(x,y)=1$.

Prove (if the statement is true) that there exists a positive integer $s$ such that
$$
x(s)=x+ap^r(p^s-1)
$$
and
$$
y(s)=y+ap^r(p^s-1)+p^{2r}(p^{2s}-1)
$$
are coprimes